# What happens to my wife's UK spouse visa if I get British passport?

Tags: united-kingdom

I am planning to apply for British citizenship this year (currently ILR). My wife and myself both living in the UK and she's holding spouse visa (she got it this year - 2017). What happens to her visa when/if I get British passport? Does she need to apply for some other visa or just leave it as is? I am asking because when she got her spouse visa I was not a British citizen so I am a but confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not affected. The semantics of the spouse visa rules are such that no difference is made between British citizens and ILR holders.